# Correctly Releasing SystemSoundID

Tags: objective-c, ios8, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc, audiotoolbox

I'm using `AudioToolbox` and `SystemSoundID` to load and play a sound.

Here's my code in my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
NSString *swipeFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"swipe" ofType:@"caf"];
NSURL *swipeFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:swipeFilePath];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)swipeFileURL, &swipe);
```

Every time I need it to play I do the following:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(swipe);
```

I know I must release it myself since it's not an obj-c object, but I'm not sure If I'm doing it correctly.

What I did was the following, except it produced an error:

```
- (void)dealloc {
AudioServiceDisposeSystemSoundID(swipe);
}
```

Warning: *Implicit declaration of function 'AudioServiceDisposeSystemSoundID' is invalid in C99*

What's the appropriate way of releasing my sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function name is:

```
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID
            ^
```

There is a 's' after Service

Comment: Whoops! You're right everything is working correctly! Can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Glad that I helped, enjoy!